# Drivers 138a:00a6 Validity Sensors in Dell vostro 3587?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, hardware

I find drives for my computer is Dell 3587.

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:00a6 Validity Sensors, Inc.
```

I try with fingerprint-gui and libpam-fprintd, but it can't find my devices. 
My ubunutu version is 18.04
Anyone can help, very thanks!